# How can i use combineReducers and reduceReducers together?

Tags: reactjs, redux, reducers

How can i use combineReducers and reduceReducers together? I want to use some reducer as combine, but also i need some reducer which should manage all state(not only part as in  combineReducer).
I try to use:

```
const combinedReducers = combineReducers({reducerA});
export const reducers= reduceReducers(combinedReducers, reducerB);
```

For same structure: 
`interface State{
    reducerAState: reducerA;
    reducerBState: reducerB;
}`

But in this case, reducerA overwrites all state on only his own, without previous state.

Answer (score 2):

That is not feasible this way. Reducer made by `combineReducers` will drop state parts with the keys which were not part of its initialization key-to-reducers map.  That is what you are experiencing and that is how it works by-design.

If you *really* have to stick to both `combineReducers` and `reducerReducers` to solve your task, then you'll have to implement 3 reducers: one for slice A, one for slice B and one which will work on both of them:

```
const sliceA = (state, action) => state + `| ${action.type} by A`;
const sliceB = (state, action) => state + `| ${action.type} by B`;
const full = (state, action) => ({ sliceA: state.sliceA + `| ${action.type} by C`, sliceB: state.sliceB + `| ${action.type} by C` });

const reducer = reduceReducers(
  combineReducers({ 
    sliceA,
    sliceB,
  }),
  full
);

const initialState = { sliceA: 'initial A', sliceB: 'initial B' };
const action = { type: 'touched' };

console.log(reducer(initialState, action));

// outputs:

Object {
  sliceA: "initial A| touched by A| touched by C",
  sliceB: "initial B| touched by B| touched by C"
}
```

But it's may be easier to just write it yourself:

```
const sliceA = (state, action) => state + `| ${action.type} by A`;
const sliceB = (state, action) => ({ 
  sliceA: state.sliceA + `| ${action.type} by B`, 
  sliceB: state.sliceB + `| ${action.type} by B`, 
})

const reducer = (state, action) => sliceB(
  {
    sliceA: sliceA(state.sliceA, action),
    sliceB: state.sliceB,
  }, 
  action
)
const initialState = { sliceA: 'initial A', sliceB: 'initial B' };
const action = { type: 'touched' };

console.log(reducer(initialState, action));

// outputs:
Object {
  sliceA: "initial A| touched by A| touched by B",
  sliceB: "initial B| touched by B"
}
```